# Wifi - "Error" , MAC Address is also unavailable

Tags: wi-fi, 2.3-gingerbread, mac-address

Just recently I Had to flash my boot partition back to it's Original, after a custom Kernel I was using had a few bugs. Upon flashing my original boot partition I used my phone as normal, but just yesterday I went to turn my wifi on, and then I get an "Error". I Think its is caused by my MAC Address because for some unknown reason to me, my MAC Address is unavailable. I Think the unavailble mac address is the cause of the problem. How would I fix this error so that I am able to use my wifi again.

[image: Wifi Error] [image]

My Phone is an LG Optimus L3 (e400f), running stock gingerbread (2.3.6)